# Converting RTMP Stream to MMS Stream

Tags: streaming, rtmp, mms, live-streaming

I have live rtmp stream which I want to push to windows media service as mms stream . Is this possible  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible according to a MS Employee (*Microsoft, MSFT*) at the **TechNet Forums** for a recently asked question titled [**RTMP to MMS restreaming**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservermedia/thread/44b94b9e-6ad9-4d6d-9e25-340c1de7a2fe).

Usually you would encode the **original media file** in the stream formats you need, and do consider using a [***Streaming Service***](https://www.google.com/search?q=streaming+service) that specializes in this type of service requirement.

More about the ***RTMP protocol*** with streaming examples [**HERE**](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=RTMP).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use VLC to transcode the stream on the fly for you.

Comment: Tried that and stream looks really bad .

Comment: Yes, but at least you have it.  VLC has TONS of options, and make sure that stream isn't bad at the source.  RTMP can't carry anything that is remotely compatible with MMS, so TRANSCODING has to be done.  You have to have computer that's powerfull enough and right options for VLC, it HAS to look OK.