# Transcode RTMP source to HTTP or MMS and stream it using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, streaming, rtmp, mms

I have several Flash applications streaming audio.

I want to **stream that audio in another protocol (HTTP or MMS)**. I search for **RTMP to MMS and HTTP transcoding** but can't find any NodeJS modules to do that job so I am guessing it is not possible.

Anyone knows if such work is possible or if there are alternatives? If anyone knows any module I can try it out I will appreciate.

*I wich I had tried something so I can show it here but I don't know where to start. I am not looking for code. I just want to know if it is possible and how. Thanks*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting RTMP Stream to MMS Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779103/converting-rtmp-stream-to-mms-stream)

Comment: While it's probably technically possible to do given a huge amount of time and engineering resources, I'd go with the more practical answer given in the duplicate answer. And, even if it were more practical, I wouldn't choose NodeJs to do it in given the multi core CPU intensive work that would be necessary.

Comment: @WiredPrairie i don't think is it is the same question. that one is about pushing a rtpm stream in windows media service. I want to stream it via NodeJS. I guess you are right about NodeJS being a bad option but I just wanted to try and see how it would work